# In a child widget, how do I get the instance of a parent widget in kivy

Tags: python, widget, kivy, instance

How do I get the instance of a parent widget from within the child widget in kivy? This is so that I can remove the child widget from within the child widget class from the parent widget.

Answer (score 0):

use `parent.<attribute>` or `root.ids.<id-of-the-widget-you-need>`

Comment: I actually solved my problem by passing the instance of the parent widget as an argument to the child widget, so that i can do whatever i want to do to the parent widget from within the child widegt.                                                                                       var = ClassObject(arg = self)